How two Data Model objects can be related in Data Cloud to be used in a report?
I have two tables which I want to bring to Data Cloud using Ingestion API.
The first table, appointments, has columns like

id
patient_id

The second table statuses has

id
appointment_id
status

I need to build a report from statuses grouped by patient_id. However, I cannot make it since these two table are not related together and I can't define a lookup or master detail relationship in Data Cloud.
Is there any way to relate two Data Model objects in Data Cloud to be used in a report?

On the Child DMO it is possible to create a new Relationship in the Relationship Tab.
Cardinality N:1 can be selected.
Then the relationship will become visible for the custom report type.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_data_model_object_relationships.htm&type=5
